# Postgresql pagination way

Tags: php, postgresql, pagination

I'm using postgresql database. I want to do an pagination for my articles, but i have no idea how to do it. I havent found a solution for postgresql (found some for mysql).

This is my query.

```
$user->getUsers(); - I call method, which is doing query..
function getUsers() 
    {
    $this->querySelect("SELECT vk_id, eu_name, eu_data, eu_society, eu_want_team, eu_notes, eu_main_profession, eu_avatar FROM users");
    }
```

I have read, that query should contain LIMIT, but it just only limit the results quantity. Can anybody tell me how to do that pagination please?

Will be very thankful..

Comment: First link using google - [Pagination  Done the Postgresql Way](https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/3/35/Pagination_Done_the_PostgreSQL_Way.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want Postgresql to do this, you're looking for OFFSET and LIMIT combined.

LIMIT means no more than that many rows will be returned.
OFFSET says to skip that many rows before beginning to return rows.

Also, you have to have an ORDER BY clause on your query for this to work.

You'll have to keep track of the page size and which page you are on.

Here is a relevant documentation page (Postgresql 8.4)

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-limit.html